# How would we go about measuring if it is more performant to call e.stopPropagation() or not?

Tags: javascript, html, event-bubbling

I want to measure if it is more beneficial to call `e.stopPropagation()` for the times when I do not need th event to propagate anymore (like almost 100% of the times), or will doing so actually incur an unnecessary overhead  which offsets any benefit of stopping the propagation to the point that it is actually more beneficial NOT to call `e.stopPropagation()` altogether?

Basically what I'm interested in is,  **how would I go about measuring this kind of stuff?**

Answer (score 1):

If you are not catching/processing this event on a higher level that doesn't matter if you stopPropagation or not.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. Btw I'm aware that it doesn't matter if i stopPropagation or not however if i have a very long "chain" of dom will it be beneficial to call e.stopPropogation to "lessen the load on the browser" ?

Comment: If you have that "long" chain of dom you will feel perfomance isues with browser rendering and those will be much bigger than anything else.

Comment: I know, i mean this as a theoretical question. will the browsers already optimise it, or would it be good practice to do a stopPropogation everytime i don't need it to propogate (which counts for 99.9% of the time)

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool call dynatrace Ajax Edition that gives you a pretty rich performance measurement toolkit.  You can check it out at: http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/  Included are loading metrics, event based metrics, a timeline view of event performance and more.  Works with IE and FF.